# Is $z^{1/n}$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be any open connected set in $\mathbb{C}$ then is $f(z)=z^{1/n}$ analytic in $G$?

It seems to be that it won't be analytic if $0$ is in G. However, I can't break $f$ into real and imaginary components so that I can use the CR equations. Or will my way not work at all? Please help.

Comment: $z^{1/n} = e^{\log(z)/n}$ so you should consider branch cuts of the complex logarithm

Comment: Put it it polar form.  Will this be analytic in the annulus $1 <|z| < r$?

Comment: On any simply connected subset of $\mathbb C$ not containing $0$, you can define it (not uniquely) analytically.

Comment: Thanks both of you